# Why does readdir() list the filenames in wrong order?

Tags: perl, readdir

I'm using the following code to read filenames from a directory and push them onto an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $directory="/var/www/out-original";
my $filterstring=".csv";
my @files;
# Open the folder
opendir(DIR, $directory) or die "couldn't open $directory: $!\n";

foreach my $filename (readdir(DIR)) {
    if ($filename =~ m/$filterstring/) {
        # print $filename;
        # print "\n";
        push (@files, $filename);
    } 
}
closedir DIR;

foreach my $file (@files) {
    print $file . "\n";
}
```

The output I get from running this code is:

```
Report_10_2014.csv
Report_04_2014.csv
Report_07_2014.csv
Report_05_2014.csv
Report_02_2014.csv
Report_06_2014.csv
Report_03_2014.csv
Report_01_2014.csv
Report_08_2014.csv
Report.csv
Report_09_2014.csv
```

Why is this code pushing the file names into the array in this order, and not from `01` to `10`?

Comment: I've edited your question title to describe the actual problem, as detailed in the answer below, so that others with the same problem may be more likely to find it.

Comment: `perl -lwe'print for @ARGV' /var/www/out-original/*.csv`

Comment: Or `chdir $dir; for my $file (sort <*.csv>) ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unix directories are not stored in sorted order.  Unix commands like `ls` and `sh` sort directory listings for you, but Perl's `opendir` function does not; it returns items in the same order the kernel does, which is based on the order they're stored in.  If you want the results to be sorted, you'll need to do that yourself:

```
for my $filename (sort readdir(DIR)) {
```

(Btw: bareword file handles, like `DIR`, are global variables; it's considered good practice to use lexical file handles instead, like:

```
opendir my $dir, $directory or die "Couldn't open $directory: $!\n";
for my $filename (sort readdir($dir)) {
```

as a safety measure.)

Comment: I've mostly stopped bothering with `readdir` and tend to use `glob` instead. E.g. : `while ( my $filename = glob ( "$dir/*" ) ) {`

Comment: @Sobrique: Be aware that `glob`, unlike `readdir`, skips files whose names start with `.`.

Comment: Unless you explicitly ask, yes. But then, that suits most of my use cases - I'm not generally interested in hidden files/directories. In the case above rather than doing a `readdir` then filtering, just using `glob ( "*.csv" )` will generally be clearer. (And also - automatically specifies the path to the file, for when you `open()` it)