# Not possible to get all content into array

Tags: perl, csv

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $directory="/var/www/out-original";
my $filterstring=".csv";
my @files;
# Open the folder
opendir my $dir, $directory or die "couldn't open $directory: $!\n";

foreach my $filename (sort(readdir($dir))) {
    if ($filename =~ m/$filterstring/) {
        # print $filename;
        # print "\n";
        push (@files, $filename);
    }
}
closedir $dir;

foreach my $file (@files) {
    open $file or die $!;
    my @array;

    while ($file) {
        #print $_;
        # Push each line of the file into array
        push (@array, $file);
    }
}
```

Hello everyone,
thanks for helping me so fast with the question about why readdir list filenames in wrong order ([Why does readdir() list the filenames in wrong order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867864/why-does-readdir-list-the-filenames-in-wrong-order)).
Now i've got another one. With this snippet it is not possible to get all content of the file into an array?

Error Message:
`Can't use string ("Report_01_2014.csv") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at parse.pl line 22`.

Thanks in advanced
Chris

Comment: FYI: You have to escape the dot in `$filterstring` and anchor at the end: `my $filterstring = qr/\.csv$/`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do

```
while( my $line = <$file> ){ # get next line, note the '<>'
   push ( @array, $line );
}
```

Also, are you sure `open $file or die $!` does what you want?

This should be what the error message is telling you, I think.

You pushed a string in ( the filename ).

So I think you want

```
open my $fh, $file or die $!;

while ( my $line = <$fh> ){...}

close $fh;
```

Comment: I'd usually go with the full file slurp approach. `@array = <$file>` - because it's in a list context, it'll read the whole file into the array.

Comment: Although I would note - in the example above, `@array` drifts out of scope before it's used for anything. I'll assume that's due to it being an example.

Comment: I prefer slurp as well. But going line by line should be fine per se

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with open. If you get into the habit of using the three parameter version of open these problems go away.